# Output processes to text file using Out-File

Tags: arrays, powershell

Trying to start processes listed in an array then get those processes and output them to a file and close the processes. Everything is working besides getting all the processes listed in the array to populate in the outputted file.  I am only getting one back.

```
# Array to iterate and open the following
$array2 = "notepad", "iexplore", "mspaint"

# Iterate through array and start process
foreach($process in $array){
    Start-Process $process 
}
# Query process and output to text file then stop processes
foreach($process in $array){
    get-process $array | Out-File process.txt
    Stop-Process -Name $process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use -Append to not overwrite process.txt
2. I don't think you actually want to get all processes each time? But I could be wrong...

```
'' | Out-File process.txt -Force # we need to empty it from previous runs
foreach($process in $array){
    get-process $process| Out-File process.txt -Append
    Stop-Process -Name $process
}
```